# Minimum specificity for a diagnostic test

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm hoping somebody here can help with an argument me and my father have been having recently regarding Covid-19 and the "false positive paradox".

My father has been making probability trees similar to the guy in this video.

https://youtu.be/6WuTNMleuQI

My father has been trying to work out how accurate the Covid-19 PCR tests are if you return a positive test.

My father has been using 94.9% specificity which I argue is not mathematically possible in the U.K.

My argument is that with 42,000,000 tests and 1,600,000 positives returned, the minimum specificity of the test must be at least 96.2% and is likely to be much higher because that would assume all of the tests returned are incorrect.

He's arguing that these aren't "real numbers" and that they're only "probabilities" I think my problem is that I don't have the necessary mathematical knowledge to explain to him where I think he's mistaken.

Who is correct here? Or are we both mistaken?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's set up a frequency table.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{Infected} & \text{Not Infected} & \text{Total} \\
\hline
\text{Test Positive} & \text{True Positive} = p_1 - n_1 & \text{False Positive} = n_1 & p_1\\
\hline
\text{Test Negative} & \text{False Negative} = p_2 - n_2 & \text{True Negative} = n_2 & p_2\\
\hline
\text{Total} & (p_1 + p_2) - (n_1 + n_2) & n_1 + n_2 & p_1 + p_2 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

All variables are counts.  The specificity is the true negatives divided by the total of those not infected; i.e., $$\text{Specificity} = S = \frac{n_2}{n_1 + n_2}.$$
We are given $p_1 = 1.6$ (in millions) and $p_1 + p_2 = 42$. Thus $p_2 = 42 - 1.6 = 40.4$.  We want to determine the smallest $S$ that allows the table to be filled correctly.  This means maximizing $n_1$ subject to the above constraints.  To see why, say $n_1 < p_1$.  Then for any fixed $n_2$, we have $$n_1 + n_2 < p_1 + n_2,$$ which in turn implies $$\frac{1}{n_1 + n_2} > \frac{1}{p_1 + n_2},$$ and $$\frac{n_2}{n_1 + n_2} > \frac{n_2}{p_1 + n_2},$$ thus showing that choosing $n_1 = p_1$ minimizes $S$ for a fixed $n_2$.  This is simply the formal mathematical way to state what you already stated:  the specificity is least under the condition that all of the positive results are assumed to be false positives.

Next, we observe that minimizing $n_2$ under the given constraints once $n_1 = p_1$ is selected, gives the minimum $S$.  If every negative result were false, that is to say, $n_2 = 0$, then the specificity is $0$.  The given data does not restrict this choice because we can fill in the table as

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{Infected} & \text{Not Infected} & \text{Total} \\
\hline
\text{Test Positive} & \text{True Positive} = 0 & \text{False Positive} = 1.6 & 1.6 \\
\hline
\text{Test Negative} & \text{False Negative} = 40.4 & \text{True Negative} = 0 & 40.4 \\
\hline
\text{Total} & 40.4 & 1.6 & 42 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Of course, this is hardly a realistic result.  It would mean that the test has *perfectly incorrect* determination--if you test positive, you're actually uninfected; and if you test negative, you're actually infected.  If among the negative results half are true and half are false, then

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{Infected} & \text{Not Infected} & \text{Total} \\
\hline
\text{Test Positive} & \text{True Positive} = 0 & \text{False Positive} = 1.6 & 1.6 \\
\hline
\text{Test Negative} & \text{False Negative} = 20.2 & \text{True Negative} = 20.2 & 40.4 \\
\hline
\text{Total} & 20.2 & 21.8 & 42 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

and the specificity would be $S = 0.926606$ assuming that all positive results are false.

What is the proportion of negative results that are false (i.e. failed to detect infection) for a specificity of $94.9\%$, assuming that all of the positives are false?  We would need to first solve for $$0.949 = \frac{n_2}{1.6 + n_2}$$ which gives $n_2 = 29.77$.  Then the detection failure rate is $$\frac{p_2 - n_2}{p_2} = 1 - \frac{29.77}{40.4} = 0.263056.$$  This means, in order for the specificity to be as low as what your father claimed, all of the positive results would need to be false positives, *and* at least $26.3\%$ of the negative results would need to be false.  This suggests that the test specificity should be substantially higher.

---

However, let's visit your father's assertion, which amounts to claiming that the observed frequencies are basically random realizations of an underlying probability distribution with some true underlying sensitivity and specificity.  While theoretically valid, due to the extremely large sample size, this point is inadequate to address the claimed specificity as I have illustrated.  If we consider the observed data as a point estimate for the true specificity, it remains highly unlikely that the true specificity is that low even with unreasonable assumptions that all of the positive results and over a quarter of the negative results are all false.

Comment: Thanks for the superb answer, as I suspected it's not feasible to have such a low specificity given the numbers that we both accept are true, I just didn't have the knowledge to put it in to actual equations.

Comment: My father still thinks I'm wrong so I may have a follow up to this later lol.

Comment: @LucasMorse The burden is now on your father to **explain** why he claims such a value for specificity, and not just assert you are wrong.  He needs to provide mathematical reasoning and point to a specific place in my reasoning where he disagrees.  That is how mathematics works and how science works.  Otherwise, there is no further discussion possible.

Comment: One thing I have noticed in your numbers is that you don't seem to have taken prevalence in to account?

Comment: With prevalence at around 3% would it even be reasonable if not impossible to expect 26.3% of people to return a false negative thus making my father's numbers impossible?